# Gradle Sync Failed in android SDK

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In Android SDK
Gradle sync failed: Unknown host 'location.app.services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.Consult IDE log for more details

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    aaptOptions {}
}

dependencies {}

repositories {
    maven { url 'services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip'; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with your Gradle file

Comment: buildscript {   repositories {  jcenter()  }  dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'   }
} allprojects { repositories {   jcenter() } }
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    } compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }    aaptOptions {
    }}dependencies {
}repositories {
    maven { url 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip' }
}

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project from scratch and seeing if that works, then copying/making changes to that as needed?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you extract the updated tools to your currendt sdk folder, problem might be solved.

dowload link: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip

**Update**

if still have problem, meaning no problem with sdk setup or so, Host related issue might be the result of proxy settings.

Please navigate to File -> Settings and in the search bar type "HTTP Proxy".
Can you please make sure that "Auto-detect" choice is chosen? if not please try with that option **AND** please after choosing Auto-detect option, at the very bottom there is Connection Test button, you type google.com and see if the result is Success.

**Update2**

You can try to locate your own local gradle distribution.
dowload the latest copy: 
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.11-all.zip

extract it in a folder, and in File--> Settings, search for Gradle this time, and under 'project-level settings' you can set gradle to your own location.
and then

Comment: Dear, not resolved. error is "Unknown host- ' location.app.services.gradle.org'"

Comment: Javin, i updated the answer, can you check please. Secondly, your gradle file is not in the normal format, meaning, compileSDK and explicit java version... its not related to the problem you currently facing, but I suggest you to use latest java in order to use proguard's newest features.

Comment: after type google.com , "Connection is successfully"- But issue is not resolved

Comment: using an untocuhed gradle distribution might solve your problem, if this also does not work, I am afraid you might want to setup your work environment from stratch.

Answer (score 0):

When going through a proxy, I found that I have had to manually specify proxy settings for Gradle in order it to sync, in addition to setting the proxy setting for Android Studio.

From the Docs on Gradle:

> Configuring an HTTP proxy (for downloading dependencies, for example)
>   is done via standard JVM system properties. These properties can be
>   set directly in the build script; for example, setting the proxy host
>   would be done with System.setProperty('http.proxyHost',
>   'www.somehost.org'). Alternatively, the properties can be specified in
>   a gradle.properties file, either in the build's root directory or in
>   the Gradle home directory.
>
> Example 11.2. Configuring an HTTP proxy
>
> **gradle.properties**
>
> ```
> systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
> systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
> systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
> systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
> systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
> ```

So add those to `gradle.properties`, then save and re-sync Gradle. If you are using HTTPS, then change `http` to `https`. If you use both HTTP and HTTPS, make sure that you have both specified.

These steps are readily available in the Gradle 2.11 Documentation, Chapter 11. The Build Environment (the link that you see in the error log "[Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle"](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html)).